# Selenium Grid 4 Nodes do not register in the Hub

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

We try to migrate our selenium nodes from one machine to many and migrate half the to cloud.

For now, the structure of the Selenium grid looks like this:

- The Hub hosted on the AWS EC2
- Mac mini node in office
- Windows node in office
- 2 Linux Nodes on the AWS EC2

When I try to connect the nodes to the Hub the nodes are not displayed in the hub and node infinite send a registration event to the Hub.

The hub 4444, 4443, and 4442 ports are open to connecting the events and hub directly.

The following logs display in the Hub when the node sends a registration event:
Node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.1.3.jar node --hub http://admin:admin@my.server.ip.address:4444 --config node.toml
22:00:24.981 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
22:00:24.985 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
22:00:25.154 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://52.14.198.246:4442 and tcp://52.14.198.246:4443
22:00:25.201 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
22:00:26.202 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
22:00:26.499 INFO [NodeServer.createHandlers] - Reporting self as: http://192.168.46.1:5555
22:00:26.723 INFO [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Detected 12 available processors
22:00:26.724 WARN [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Overriding max recommended number of 12 concurrent sessions. Session stability and reliability might suffer!
22:00:26.725 WARN [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - One browser session is recommended per available processor. Safari is always limited to 1 session per host.
22:00:26.726 WARN [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Overriding this value for Internet Explorer is not recommended. Issues related to parallel testing with Internet Explored won't be accepted.
22:00:26.726 WARN [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Double check if enabling 'override-max-sessions' is really needed
22:00:26.764 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Chrome for {"browserName": "chrome","se:webDriverExecutable": "D:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe","platformName": "WIN10"} 12 times
22:00:26.774 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: relative, name, id
22:00:27.169 INFO [NodeServer$1.start] - Starting registration process for Node http://192.168.46.1:5555
22:00:27.170 INFO [NodeServer.execute] - Started Selenium node 4.1.3 (revision 7b1ebf28ef): http://192.168.46.1:5555
22:00:27.181 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
```

node.toml

```
[node]
override-max-session = true
max-session = 5
```

Hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.1.3.jar hub --config hub.toml
18:59:15.183 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
18:59:15.189 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
18:59:15.352 INFO [BoundZmqEventBus.<init>] - XPUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4442, advertising as tcp://172.31.45.214:4442], XSUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4443, advertising as tcp://172.31.45.214:4443]
18:59:15.412 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://172.31.45.214:4442 and tcp://172.31.45.214:4443
18:59:15.449 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
18:59:16.450 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
18:59:17.267 INFO [Hub.createHandlers] - Requiring authentication to connect
18:59:17.420 INFO [Hub.execute] - Started Selenium Hub 4.1.3 (revision 7b1ebf28ef): http://172.31.45.214:4444
19:00:24.011 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: id, name, relative
19:00:34.785 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: relative, name, id
```

hub.toml

```
[router]
username = admin
password = admin
```

What did I miss in the configuration?

**UPDATE:**

When I run in the debug mode I saw a connection timeout to the node:

```
13:45:22.386 DEBUG [LocalDistributor.add] - Exception while adding Node http://52.14.57.227:5555
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException: connection timed out: /52.14.57.227:5555
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:80)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:51)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:124)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.TracedHttpClient.execute(TracedHttpClient.java:55)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.remote.RemoteNode.getStatus(RemoteNode.java:208)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.add(LocalDistributor.java:305)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.register(LocalDistributor.java:291)
        at org.openqa.selenium.events.EventListener.accept(EventListener.java:43)
        at org.openqa.selenium.events.EventListener.accept(EventListener.java:25)
        at org.openqa.selenium.events.zeromq.UnboundZmqEventBus$PollingRunnable.lambda$notifyListeners$2(UnboundZmqEventBus.java:301)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connection timed out: /52.14.57.227:5555
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:179)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:108)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:262)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /52.14.57.227:5555
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:261)
        ... 9 more
13:45:22.386 FINEST [LoggingHandler.channelUnregistered] - [id: 0xef015bd6] UNREGISTERED
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete error tracelogs.

Comment: Add all trace log from start

Comment: You haven't shown us the commands you have used to start the hub/node.

Comment: Added commands in the start of the log, and also a .toml file

Answer (score 0):

When I run the hub in the --log-level FINEST I found that the hub can not connect to the node by port 5555.

And the solution was open the port 5555 on the machines:

- AWS EC2 using the security group
- Windows and macOS using the firewall inbound rules